# IE9 local filesystem security prevents js execution

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer-9, localhost

I'm developing a local JavaScript webapp for demo purposes. The webapp consists of a single HTML page and a few JS files that are included into the app using `<script>` tags in `<head>`.

When I run this file (from the local filesystem on windows) on FF or Chromium, everything is as it should be - the app works fine.

When I run it in IE9, there is a "Internet Explorer restricted this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls" and the app fails to load properly. Clicking on "Allow content" does not help that much because the app already is a train wreck.

How when I host a local webserver with

```
python -m http.server 8888
```

and point IE to it - everything works fine.

Because this is a corporate setting I am not interested in changing the security settings.

I've dealt with the problem by sending these files to a server, but the questions remains: why does IE treat files from the filesystem (within the same directory even) as some sort of cross-site request or security risk?

PS. Bonus WTF: When opening the page with the developer tools on, everything is ok.

EDIT: In case you're wandering: I did add a closing script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why does IE treat files from the filesystem [as a] security risk?

Historical Reasons.

When Microsoft came up with the idea of web security Zones, they originally decided that the My Computer Zone, containing the local filesystem, was more trusted than the Internet Zone.

This almost sounds like a sensible thing to do, except that (a) users expect web pages they download not to gain a load of privileges when run from the hard disc, and (b) lots of programs download files from the internet and put them in a predictable place... so if you can persuade them to download an HTML file, you are persauding them to inject privileged script into the My Computer Zone.

The original settings for the My Computer Zone were to allow ActiveX controls to install and run without prompting. This meant that if you could ever get some HTML onto the filesystem, you essentially had an execute-arbitrary-code security vulnerability. There were *lots* of web exploits that leveraged this as part of their infection mechanism to load malware.

Microsoft feared any change to My Computer Zone security settings would break applications that used the web browser control to render their own HTML content as part of their UI. So instead, the web browser control defaulted to existing settings, and browsers such as IE that used it were invited to enable "Local Machine Lockdown" mode, which would drop the extra privileges My Computer Zone pages got by default. IE turned this on by default.

Unfortunately in a classic over-reaction, "Local Machine Lockdown" was not just the same level of privilege as the Internet Zone would have been, but even more restrictive - blocking JavaScript as well as ActiveX. This broke pages that users had saved to the hard disc, so to work around that IE adds a marker to pages it downloads to allow them to escape the (formerly privileged, now restricted) My Computer Zone and be treated as normal Internet Zone pages.

This is the [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628.aspx) and you can include it in your static files to make them behave normally too.

Of course this makes the added restrictiveness of Local Machine Lockdown completely pointless, as any file can opt out.

But then the whole thing is now completely pointless, because since then the default settings of the Local Machine Zone have been changed and now resemble the Internet Zone more closely, not allowing arbitrary ActiveX. So that's a lot of confusing added complexity for no gain whatsoever.

Comment: Informative, useful and interesting. I guess that I sometimes forget that IE9 is still IE, with all the legacy that entails.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have this exact same scenario and I am seeing the same result. i have tried your suggestion of adding the mark of the web but it didn't help. Is there a solution here?

Comment: @GregoryKuhn: Mark of the Web does fix it, but you have to be careful to add it in the right place (immediately after any doctype), with the right inline length, and—what trips most people up—with Windows CRLF line endings, not normal LFs.

Comment: @bobince Thanks for the reply. I have tried adding a MOTW  like this: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
` Within IE, the page shows that the Zone is set to Internet | Protected Mode: Off. I am using the library D3 and I am still getting a `SCRIPT5: Access is denied. ` error from within the d3 javascript library. Specifically: here: `xhr.send = function(method, data, callback) {
      if (arguments.length === 2 && typeof data === "function") callback = data, data = null;
      request.open(method, url, true);
`I am also using the correct line endings.

Comment: @GregoryKuhn: OK that's a different problem and not IE specific. You're trying to do a cross-site XMLHttpRequest from the filesystem origin to a remote site origin, which is blocked as it's an XSS security risk. The URL in the MotW doesn't actually put you in the origin of that site, it only switches to Internet Mode (so yeah, it's pretty pointless).

Comment: @bobince oh I see. Thanks very much for info. Incidentally, I am merely trying to graph some data by loading a data file from the user's local file system so I can understand the security concerns. This actually works in firefox but not in chrome or IE.